# Create netcat style consumer with Apache Camel and netty4: route

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, netty

I try to create a tcp receiver which can get data over a certain port and store it into a file. I use Apache Camel 2.16.1, Spring Boot 1.3.0-RELEASE and netty 4.0.33 for this.

My setup is like that described in the camel-spring-boot starter, the route definition is this:

```
@Component
public class Routes {

  @Bean
  RoutesBuilder myRouter() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from( "netty4:tcp://192.168.0.148:10001?sync=false&allowDefaultCodec=false&decoder=#decoder")
        .to("file:/temp/printjobs");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I created a decoder that looks like this:

```
public class RawPrinterDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf> {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg,
            List<Object> out) throws Exception {

        byte[] array = new byte[msg.readableBytes()];
        msg.getBytes(0, array);
        String string = new String(array);
        out.add(string);

        System.out.println("Received " + msg.readableBytes()
                + " in a buffer with maximum capacity of " + msg.capacity());
        System.out.println("50 first bytes I received: "
                + string.substring(0, 50));
    }
}
```

Data is sent by using this command:

```
cat binaryfile | nc 192.168.0.148 10001
```

The route is built but when I use it I am unable to get the former `binaryfile` in its original shape and rather receive several blocks of data:

```
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 1024 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 1024
Received 16384 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 16384
Received 16384 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 16384
Received 16384 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 16384
Received 5357 in a buffer with maximum capacity of 16384
```

(As you can see my original file is processed in blocks of increasing size and it 70839 byte in size)

The received blocks are each stored in a separate file because I am not able to join the parts:

```
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-1
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-3
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-5
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-7
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-9
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-11
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-13
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-15
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-17
24.11.2015  23:47             1.024 ID-Tower-53867-1448405258593-0-19
...
```

How can I identify the first and last block and join them in the decoder ? I made an approach which involved `getMaxMessagesPerRead()` but this returns `16` and my file is split into 20 blocks of data.

Comment: You need to configure a codec, because its text or binary based you need to setup that, there is textline=true which is text based. And set sync=false as you do not send back a response.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for those details, I obviously was unable to grasp that by reading the docs :-( Do I need to configure a codec even when I want to keep the data sent "as-is" (which in my case is just a pile of binary stuff) ? My first attempt is to collect the data, in a second step I will have to analyze the content, but that is a different story (which I fear will lead to a new SO question ;-))

Comment: You need to study/learn how codec in netty works. You need some kind of length / termination etc in the codec so netty know when the data is done.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I will decide whether to use mina2 or netty4 and then have a look at codecs. And your book, since too much time has passed since I last did ;-)

Comment: @ClausIbsen If you can spare some time I would like to ask you to have a look at my update above. I have a codec in place now but haven't found a way to set a marker for the end of stream because I can not modify the sending application. I guess this information needs to be retrieved on tcp level.